# Embedding an SWF animation at a specific location in an AS3 project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, embed

I'm doing a project in AS3 (no external libraries or Flex) and I need to embed an explosion animation over a tile when it gets destroyed.  I have a small explosion animation but I don't know how I can get it to play at a specific location.  Is there a way to do this? I've tried embedding it like so:

```
[Embed(source="../assets/64x48.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")] private var Explosion:Class 
var explosion:MovieClip;
explosion = new Explosion();
explosion.play();
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything.  If not an SWF, I also have a sprite sheet of an explosion I could use, but I'm not sure how to animate a sprite without using an external library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach within your swf Movieclip you want to play, you must perform the following. swf convert to bytearray after, it must be restored.

### EDIT

I checked your swf file. however, your swf file contents not `MovieClip`, but `AVM1Movie` file. so It is quite difficult to directly embedded. because `AVM1Movie` file convert to `MovieClip` Algorithm. but don't worry. using a ForcibileLoader easily available.

download a [ForcibileLoader](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-58b14f2b.html)

original ForcibileLoader [here](http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/ForcibleLoader/src/org/libspark/utils/ForcibleLoader.as)

refer a following code. I tested great work.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    import org.libspark.utils.ForcibleLoader;

    public class TestProject2 extends Sprite
    {
        private var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        private var mc:MovieClip;

        public function TestProjec2t()
        {
            var fLoader:ForcibleLoader = new ForcibleLoader(loader);
            fLoader.load(new URLRequest("../asset/64x48.swf"));
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoaded);
            this.addChild(loader);
        }

        private function onSwfLoaded(e:Event):void 
        {
            trace(e.currentTarget.content);
            mc = e.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;
            mc.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            mc.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
            mc.gotoAndPlay(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ok I can see the swf in the window now, but it plays automatically in the top left corner, and when I try to run mc.play() I get a null object reference error

Comment: Did you write something like the code above? Can you give me a link to your source. Reviewing'll

Comment: here's a link to the github: https://github.com/Hiero7/EATechnicalTest/blob/master/src/Tile.as

Comment: I pretty much copied your code exactly though, besides changing variable names

Comment: somewhat related, not sure if you would know how to do this, but the swf I'm using just keeps looping and I'm not sure how to stop it.  Once the animation finishes it should stop and disappear, but it just stays there looping forever.  How can I check when it's done with the initial animation to stop it?

Comment: edit: i just set a timer to callback when the animation ends to stop it.  It's not exactly elegant but it works